# Changing AppDelegate.m to AppDelegate.mm and modifying AppDelegate.h when upgrading React Native version from 0.66.4 to 0.71.3

Tags: javascript, ios, reactjs, react-native

AppDelegate.h (original)

```
#import <React/RCTBridgeDelegate.h>
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <UserNotifications/UserNotifications.h>
@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate, RCTBridgeDelegate, UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate>

@property (nonatomic, strong) UIWindow *window;

@end
```

AppDelegate.h (modified)

```
#import <RCTAppDelegate.h>
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@interface AppDelegate : RCTAppDelegate
@end
```

How can I include UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate in the modified version?

Also, documentation suggests to delete AppDelegate.m and create new AppDelegate.mm with the given code then how can I include the other modules that were there in previous AppDelegate.m file?

I tried upgrading react native version from 0.66.4 to 0.71.3

Answer (score 0):

Try with this:

```
#import <RCTAppDelegate.h>
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <UserNotifications/UNUserNotificationCenter.h>

@interface AppDelegate : RCTAppDelegate <UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate>

@end
```